# How to update links on excel when a file was changed by someone else on a shared network

Tags: vba, excel

If someone makes a change to a file on a shared network, I need that change to be reflected in the excel file with the links.  However, it will only update now when you open the original file first.  How do I update these links without having to open the original file?  Is there VBA code that can update links for a specific worksheet? Thank you

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a shortcut key to refresh the content. You can just press F9 key.

Comment: Yes, there is a vba code. ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink ThisWorkbook.LinkSources  will update the hyper links.